# How does $\frac{z+a+\sqrt{\rho^2+(z+a)^2}}{z-a+\sqrt{\rho^2+(z-a)^2}}=c$ become $(\frac{(1-c)^2\rho}{2\sqrt c a})^2+(\frac{(1-c)z}{(1+c)a})^2=1$?

Tags: geometry

This is an exercise for which I have the solution. My question has to do more with the process of understanding that the below formula gives us some equipotential surfaces and that happens to be an elliptic one:

$$\frac {z+a + \sqrt{\rho^2 + (z+a)^2}}{z-a + \sqrt{\rho^2 + (z-a)^2}}= c$$
where c is some constant.

I should note that this was part of an exercise in which I had to find the potential of an electric  rod which is located in the z- axis and has no radius in the x,y plane. What I want to know is how do I even begin to think of reaching the equation of an ellipse? In the exercise it is not mentioned why this end up being the equation of an ellipse, it only derives the equation as if somehow knew that it would be an ellipse. So basically how do I start, or what do I need to consider to get this:

$$\left(\frac {(1-c)^2 \rho}{2 \sqrt c a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac {(1-c)z}{(1+c)a}\right)^2=1 $$

As I said, a solution is given, but I don't want to simply copy that. I want to be able to understand that you can change the initial equation into something and that something ends up being the equation of an elliptic equipotential surface. I tried some calculations myself, but I end up with a bunch of factors and then I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with

$ \dfrac{ z+a + \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z + a)^2 }} { z - a + \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z -a)^2 }} = c$

Cross multiply to obtain

$z+a + \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z + a)^2} = c (z - a + \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z -a)^2 }) $

Combine like terms,

$ z(1 - c) + a (1 + c) = c \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z - a)^2 } - \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z + a)^2 } $

Square both sides,

$ z^2 (1 - c)^2 + a^2 (1 + c)^2 + 2 z a (1 - c^2 ) = c^2 ( \rho^2 + (z-a)^2 ) + \rho^2 + (z + a)^2 - 2 c \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z - a)^2 }\sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z + a)^2 } $

Combining the terms on the right hand side, we get,

$ z^2 (1 - c)^2 + a^2 (1 + c)^2 + 2 z a (1 - c^2 ) = \rho^2 (1 + c^2) + z^2 (c^2 + 1) + a^2 (c^2 + 1 ) + 2 z a (1 - c^2 ) -2 c \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z - a)^2 }\sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z + a)^2 } $

And this reduces to

$ z^2 (-2c) + a^2 (2 c) - \rho^2 (1 + c^2) = - 2 c \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z - a)^2 }\sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z + a)^2 } $

Square both sides again,

$ z^4 (4c^2) + a^4 (4 c^2) + \rho^4 (1 + c^2)^2 - 8 c^2 a^2 z^2 + 4 c (1 + c^2) z^2 \rho^2 - 4 c (1 + c^2) a^2 \rho^2 = 4 c^2 ( \rho^2 + (z - a)^2 )(\rho^2 + (z + a)^2 ) $

Expanding the right hand side results in

$ z^4 (4c^2) + a^4 (4 c^2) + \rho^4 (1 + c^2)^2 - 8 c^2 a^2 z^2 + 4 c (1 + c^2) z^2 \rho^2 - 4 c (1 + c^2) a^2 \rho^2 = 4 c^2 ( \rho^4 + \rho^2 (2 z^2 + 2 a^2 ) + z^4 + a^4 - 2 a^2 z^2 ) $

This reduces to

$ \rho^4 ( (1 + c^2)^2 - 4 c^2) + z^2 \rho^2 ( 4 c(1 + c^2) - 8 c^2 ) + a^2 \rho^2 ( -4c (1 + c^2 ) - 8 c^2 ) = 0$

Simplifying further, and dividing by $\rho^2 $

$ \rho^2 ( (1 - c^2)^2 ) + z^2  (4c) (1 - c)^2 + a^2 ( -4c) (1 + c)^2 = 0 $

Take the last term to the right hand side and divide by it, you get,

$ \left( \dfrac{ \rho (1 - c^2) }{2 \sqrt{c} (1 + c) } \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{ z (1 - c) }{(1 + c)} \right)^2 = 1 $

Which is the ellipse equation.

Comment: When I tried to do it like this I stopped half way through, because I didn't know what to do next. My idea was to group everything that had z in once side and everything with $\rho$ in the other, but there well many mixed terms which i couldn't separate in order to late transform the big expression I had in something which depends on z and rho, like an ellipse that depends on x and y in the xy-plane. Thanks a alot!